# android - the package conflict with an existing package by the same name - but it doesn't

Tags: android, galaxy

I am having a problem installing my app onto customers Galaxy s8 phones. I am not aware of any issues on any other phones.

Customers first reported a 505 error from the Google play store. When I got them to install the app directly from my website it gives an "the package conflict with an existing package by the same name" error.

So I changed the package name for them to a random series of numbers, and still the same error.
One customer has been very helpful and has even reset the phone to factory defaults, but still gets the same error.

Any ideas of anything that could be wrong?
Could calls to depreciated functions cause this?

Many Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, having the following permission

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

prevents the app being installed on a Galaxy S8, returns the 505 error.

Comment: Wich permission?

Comment: which permission ?

Comment: Have the same issue but I have C2D_MESSAGE permissions in previous builds and it was ok. How did you found an issue?

Comment: Hi Anber, 

I had the same issue, worked fine, then suddenly stopped.

I used the samsung developer site were you are able to test on real samsung devices -
 http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/galaxy/rtlDeviceList.action